# Invalid passbook generated in php server

Tags: javascript, php, ios, passbook, passkit

I am trying to create support passbook from ios6 and later. I found an example that works perfectly but when trying to adapt it to my server it generates invalid passbook. The original project is in this url:

https://github.com/SimonWaldherr/passkit.php

The only change I made was putting him temporary files directory of my server. The certificates have left the same as shown in the example and everything exactly the same. My server is https. What can it be wrong?

The url from my test server is:

https://hot.es/passkit.php-master/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with your certificate. This is what I got when I tried to download it.

```
Sep 15 13:32:01 iPhone MobileSafari[892] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.apple.demo/nmyuxofgnb. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
Sep 15 13:32:01 iPhone MobileSafari[892] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.
```

You can debug this yourself by attempting to download your pass to a device. While the only error you will get from the UI is something like "Safari cannot download this file" there is more in your device logs. Plug your device into a computer with XCode on it, open `Window -> Organizer` or `CMD + Shift + 2`, find your device in the sidebar and choose the `console` sub-option.